# Looping through a hash

Tags: haxe

In my code below, the fields length was always 0, and I'm pretty sure there are some key-value pairs in it.

```
var fields = Reflect.fields(_commandMap);
trace("mapping "+fields.length);
```

Comment: Without more context it's pretty difficult to tell what's happening.  From the docs it says that Reflect.fields is only guaranteed to work on anonymous objects... and to use Type.getClassFields() otherwise.  Maybe try that? (http://haxe.org/api/reflect)  Otherwise, post more context :)

Comment: Thanks guys, my intension was to get keys in a Hash,as i am a flash developer,i know we can loop a object in AS3 like that:
for (var key:String in object){
  
}
i want to do the same thing in Haxe, as what i thought the Hash might be the equivalent of Ojbect, however, i just cant get the keys defined in the Hash instance... Or Hash in Haxe is not iterable at all??

Answer (score 1):

You can't access values in a array form in a Hash.

Here is a Hash

```
var a = new Hash();
a.set("hello", 0);
a.set("bonjour", 1);
a.set("ohai", 2);
```

Here is some way you can access values/keys :

```
for (value in a)
{
    trace(value); //Will trace 0, 1, 2 (no assurance that it will be in that order)
}

for (key in a.keys())
{
    trace(key); //Will trace hello, bonjour, ohai (no assurance that it will be in that order)
}
```

If you want to convert your Hash into an Array, use [Lambda](http://haxe.org/api/lambda):

```
var valueArray = Lambda.array(a);
trace(valueArray[0]); //can be 0, 1 or 2

//since keys() returns an Iterator, not an Iterable, we cannot use Lambda here...
var keyArray = [];
for (key in a.keys()) keyArray.push(key);
trace(keyArray[0]); //can be hello, bonjour or ohai
```